# Flexbox dynamic height smart positioning possible?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: Flexbox Question]

I'm wondering if this is possible to achieve in flexbox. I have some bootstrap panels that are dynamic in height, shown on the left and I'd like order them as shown in example a or b. That is i'd like them to be dynamically positioned to save as much screenspace as possible. Is this possible?

In example A the panels are pushed up as tightly as possible in each column.

In example B the panels are moved between columns to save even more screenspace.

link to image in full size: https://www.dropbox.com/s/knv5mtfwvscvff3/flexbox_question.png?dl=0

Comment: nop, it goes drawing columns or rows, you need the well known http://masonry.desandro.com/  you should give HTML and CSS instead just a screen shot alone in order to get some helps ;)

Comment: thank you. I'll look into it. Apologies for posting a duplicate. I didn't find it during my search before posting.